# Node.js SWIG is it support Async function?

Tags: html, node.js, swig-template

I have dynamic html page what using Node.js and SWIG template engine. I need call function from my SWIG template to get user data from database to render page content. SWIG call function but not wait for response from database.
So, is it possible to call async function and return data to swig template?

My SWIG template: todos.html

```
<body>
{%set todos=getTodos()%}
{%for item in todos%}
  <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  <div>{{item.completed}}</div>
{%endfor%}

</body>
```

My node server (using express):

```
.......
swig.setDefaults({locals:{getTodos:function(input){
       setTimeout(function(){
        return [
                {name:"First todo",completed:false},
                {name:"Same name",completed:true},
               ]
       },5000)
    })
........
```

But page was rendered without waiting for data that come from "timeout".

Comment: I think the right thing would be to first call your async function, then get the result (in .then, or via await, or callback, whatever), then as you have all the needed data render your template and send it back to the client. I mean not to try calling async function inside the template. Would you mind to provide us with the code that's not working for you?

Comment: Ok, updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically no, you cannot use the async functions directly in the template. It's not supported.

But you can still do what you want by simply getting all the data you need asynchronously first and then rendering the swig template.

Here is the minimal example:

```js
const swig = require('swig');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const swigEngine = new swig.Swig();
app.engine('html', swigEngine.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

const loadTodos = function (callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        const todos = [
            {name: "First todo", completed: false},
            {name: "Same name", completed: true},
        ];

        callback(null, todos);
    }, 1000)
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // So first you get the data asynchronously 
    loadTodos(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(400);
            return;
        }
        
        res.render('index', {todos: data});
    })
});

app.listen(5555, () => console.log('Server is running on port 5555.'))
```

Also you template gets more simple if you do it like that:

```html
{%for item in todos%}
 <!-- You have missed the curly brackets here {{}} -->
 <div>{{item.name}}</div>
 <div>{{item.completed}}</div>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Ok, but it's not very good if I need to use my code many times in different pages.  
Found this comment but this don't work at this time.
https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/pull/333/commits/fb3476dc099567a7c36c35cf4d778e62b736cce9

Comment: @OleksandrKyrpa What do you mean? Could you describe the problem in a detail? If you don't want to repeat the code that fetches the data for each route you could extract it into a separate function and then just call it. (Please see the edited answer)

Comment: Anyway, you'd need to get the data somehow: either in the template or in a controller. So this part will be repeated.

Comment: I do not want to add routes to all my pages that will be using getTodos().

Comment: Route means the url + the handler to generate the HTML for the page (aka Controller). So you won't be able to create any page without adding the route. Anyway, I want to point this out again. Here is the flow for SWIG: Load data -> Pass it to SWIG -> Return the rendered page to the client. There is no other way.

Comment: Yes I understand and use it in my projects. But somthink like this wiil be amazing.
`  {% async %}
        ...........
 {{ getTodos("user_id") }}
        ...........
   {% endasync %}`
Because, I will be implement it one time and then use it in different templates and "routes".

Comment: May be is it possible by creating custom "tag" or "extension"?
https://voorhoede.github.io/swig/docs/api/#setTag

Comment: I've got a bad news man :) Take a look at swig.render function: https://node-swig.github.io/swig-templates/docs/#usage it's synchronous (no promises, not callback, no nothing, just sync execution). This basically means that whatever we do - SWIG won't be able to handle async stuff.

Comment: But, you could take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252487/express-async-templating Seems, there are other template engines that potentially support the async data loading you want.

Comment: @OleksandrKyrpa Do we still have something left uncovered in this conversation/answer?

Comment: All clear, I moved to nunjucks 
 that support async function/filter https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#addfilter